# How to get back to program's main code (user-space) while attaching to de bugger

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I have a small program that I wanted to debug.
I run OllyDbg version 2 and attached the program to the debugger.

I received this window:
[image]

You can see that the addresses are from the Kernel memory.
I want to see the code of the program, I tried to double click on all the opened thread but everyone are in a kernel memory.
I noticed that the header is:

> CPU - main thread, module USER32

Maybe the problem is that it showing me the module's memory and not the program's memory.

Any idea how I can switch to the program's memory (user-space memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it.

Just right click on the code, choose `Select module` and choose the main module which is usually on the top.

[image]